# Securely storing username and password in mysql where php script will need to post fields in clear text

Tags: mysql, passwords, encryption

I am creating a cron job, that runs a php script that will login onto an external website using curl and scrapes a page to extract data.

Now the question I have is that I need to store the credentials in the database, how can I store this securely. The problem is that the curl script would need to post the username and password in clear text.

The service is similar as to what Mint.com does, ie pulling billing information using users credentials.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data can be encrypted (See the examples in [openssl_encrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/function.openssl-encrypt.php)), then decrypted when you need it in your php script and pass them unencrypted as a string concatenated to your call of curl.

Answer (score 0):

If the external system does not provide an alternate (non-password-based) authentication method (unlike e.g. facebook, which support OAuth) then you have no good choices. Either your app will always ask for a password - a bit awkward and not automation-compatible. When this is not good enough then the DB+app together have to know the password, so anyone with access to both will know it too. The only thing you can do is to make sure that access to only one of them is not enough: create a secret key for the app, and hide it from DB admins (put it in the source). Use this as key for encrypting passwords (you might want to build the actual encryption key with this secret key + some invariant user-specific data [e.g. userID] to improve the protection of the secret key). And so you can store the encrypted passwords in the database. There are pretty many privacy concerns though. One's password should never be discoverable by anyone else, but here this is not the case. If the DB is on the webserver, admins will see both the encrypted passwords and the secret key - fail. The app will have unlimited access to the password so its developers will have that too (e.g. they can hide snippet to send an email).